# MAAS Failed Comissioning

Tags: maas

I am trying to commision node (Dell T330) which has been automatically enlisted in the Nodes when powered on first time. The first network interface is connected to network with Internet access, node is set to PXE boot and power type is set to IPMI 2.0.

The node fails to comission with following error message:

```
Aug 14 13:02:00 uklab-maas maas.power: [info] Changing power state (cycle) of node: nova2 (qdk6g4)
Aug 14 13:02:00 uklab-maas maas.node: [info] nova2: Commissioning started
Aug 14 13:04:15 uklab-maas maas.drivers.power.ipmi: [warn] Failed to change the boot order to PXE 10.22.230.202: /usr/sbin/ipmi-config: connection timeout
Aug 14 13:04:49 uklab-maas maas.power: [error] Error changing power state (cycle) of node: nova2 (qdk6g4)
Aug 14 13:04:49 uklab-maas maas.node: [info] nova2: Status transition from COMMISSIONING to FAILED_COMMISSIONING
Aug 14 13:04:49 uklab-maas maas.node: [error] nova2: Marking node failed: Power cycle for the node failed: Could not contact node's BMC: Connection timed out while performing power action.  Check BMC configuration and connectivity and try again.
```

A few seconds later, the event log shows that BMC can be reached again.

[Node Events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNTI9.png)

Ubuntu 16.04 /
MAAS version: 2.2.0 (bzr6054-0ubuntu2~16.04.1)

Would someone have any hints on how to resolve issue?

Comment: What version of iDRAC does that server have?  Is MAAS able to power on the node?  Have you tried manually adding the node (ignoring the auto discovery results)?

Comment: It is iDRAC version 8.
MAAS is able to power on the node. I checked by power on/off node via MAAS WebUI which works fine.
The node is visible in in MAAS. It's about the commissioning which fails.

Comment: Commissioning also fails when manually adding the node.